# Hiding a tab, without killing it with Chrome API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any way, with the current Chrome Extensions API that I can hide a chrome tab without actually killing it - that is, restore the content of the tab without having to reload it?

Answer (score 2):

Currently (Nov 2020) this is only possible in Firefox (desktop). Chrome and other browsers do not support `browser.tabs.hide()` API

Answer (score -2):

Simply search through the MSN documentation pages next time: tabs.hide()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/hide